# Arduino Error 1 expected unqualified-id before 'else'

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

Arduino Error: Where have i gone wrong in this simple and extremely small amount of code to receive the above error message? I cannot figure it out.

```
int ledPin = A0;
int bumpPin = A1;
void setup() {
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(bumpPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
digitalRead(bumpPin);
if (bumpPin == HIGH);
digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
}else{
digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
}
```

Comment: I'd say you need a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). (Also, why did you tag this as Java?)

Comment: thanks very constructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely read a tutorial on C++. What you have here is a basic syntax error. An if/else statements uses the following syntax:

```
if (condition) {
    // Do stuff here
} else {
    // Do other stuff here
}
```

You have a semi colon after your condition in your if statement. Change that to a curly brace and you’re good! So this:

```
if (bumpPin == HIGH);
```

Should be this:

```
if (bumpPin == HIGH) {
```

[Here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html) is an online C++ tutorial.

[Here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html) is that tutorial’s section on if statements.

Comment: Tried that with the error: 'else' without a previous 'if'

Comment: No, don't read a tutorial on _C/C++_ because that language does not exist. Read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or adequate tutorial on C++.

Comment: Yes it did end up working missing a brace at the end of the code thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: `bumpPin == HIGH` will always be `false`.